# torch vision: libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::length_error: vector

Tags: python-3.x, clang, torchvision

recently, I started having a weird error when importing torch vision. I have freshly installed MacBook M1, latest Monterey build 12.3.1. Mini-forge is the first thing installed.
When I try to import torchvision I get following error:

```
Python 3.9.12 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Mar 24 2022, 23:24:38) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
PyDev console: using IPython 8.2.0
Python 3.9.12 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Mar 24 2022, 23:24:38) 
[Clang 12.0.1 ] on darwin

In[2]: import torchvision
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::length_error: vector
Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

I tried googling it and cannot find any solution. It might be connected to recent Monterey update? I frankly don't know what happened. Can you pls, help?

Comment: The post started with "Hi guys, recently, ..." but it gets cut off for some reason.

Comment: Using: - pytorch==1.10.2
    - torchvision==0.11.3

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I upgraded torch from 1.10.2 to 1.11.0. Downgrade helped me.

Comment: In my case, I upgraded to pytorch 1.11.0 and torchvision 0.12.0, with appropriete dependencies using conda. And it helped me. However, I don't know what happened in the first place. I might updated some different packege and it broke the compatibility with pytorch....

Comment: Same, dependecy hell here. What did the trick for me using MAcbook M2 was to export the right environment variables (CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64) while using conda and install the latest pytorch version, see here https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#start-locally